# Distinguish default or command-line argument

Tags: python, argparse

Consider

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("--foo", type=str, default="bar", help="description")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now I would like to know if `args.foo` got its value due to the default, or because the user specified `myprogram --foo bar`. How can I distinguish that?

**Edit:** A big plus would be if the docstring still reflected the default.

Comment: Check if it is equal to `parser.get_default('foo')` ?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I want to know if the use specified a value equal to the default, or if argparse used the default

Comment: Oh, yes... That was even clearly stated in your question! ;)

Comment: With your setup, the `help` doesn't show the 'default'

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj . I was too minimalistic. I edited to correct

Answer (score 3):

Since the definition of default is *use that value, if nothing is provided* it is  not be possible. You could change the default to `None`, and handle it by setting it to the real *default*, however.

```
 if args.foo is None:
    # set to intended default
 else:
    # was provided by user
```

Comment: Agreed! But it does give a less nice docstring.